# Is it OK to let the user use colored tags to associate data sets or keywords?

Tags: interaction-design, design, color, users, human-interface-guideline

I am debating with my boss regarding whether tags should be coloured or not. I feel that colouring tags will just work as fun for the user. A user won't remember what colour he has assigned to a particular group of keywords. For instance, the user applied red for the "offers" keyword and later after somedays while doing a campaign they assigned red colour to "Diwali festival". So use case of colour tags doesn't satisfy the need of it. However, the boss says to let them assign any colour what they wish. There is no need for grouping keywords of the same colour.

Please help me with this!

Comment: What? "here is no need for grouping keywords of the same colour." So your argument is that tags should be grouped per colour, but your boss points out that there may be arbitrary tags of the same colour...so then grouping wouldn't make much sense...so why group them? Where and how do you group them?

Answer (score 0):

I know what you feel :)
When I read your problem, I think your boss is bossy and struggles to follow suggestions from employees but in another case I think your boss could hear and follow suggestions if he/she has good reason for it. For example, tag using with 1 color may be better than 5 colors because it makes the user not confused, makes it clean and we can keep it consistent. While your boss is still thinking that using 5 colors is the best choice you can use A/B Testing with users to build one design like your boss and one design what you want. Don't forget to record a video or invite your boss to the A/B Testing.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for answering. I will sure take A/B Test of it.

Answer (score 0):

For me the situation is not quite clear.
a) You offer software for others, who can do e.g. project management with it or
b) you work all together in your company with this software internally

For case a, you should leave it up to the others how they use colors. After all, a priority can also be represented with the colors.
For b it is not a matter of software but of internal rules. -In the end, it is the boss who defines them.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, as always, on how the product is used and the context of use. I‘d like to mention two UX aspects that coloured tags can add:

### Boosted efficiency

If users are spending hours tagging things as part of their daily job, they can do that faster by using colours. It becomes an automatism, improving *Time on Task*. Our brain is very efficient in recognising colours and other patterns.

If users tend to only use these tags once in a while, there will be no effect on task performance.

### Stronger sense of ownership

By customising a product, for example by using colours, users are making it their own. This will change how they feel about the product, and probably bump satisfaction scores.